# Do "temporary" followers have special abilities?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do others followers (e.g. Leah, Tyreal) that join you in some parts of the story have special abilities (buff, active skills, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from cinematic powers, the answer thus far appears to be no, unless they're very well hidden.

Though do be careful - they have the power of being willful jerks, and Tyreal really loves to pull Champion packs or attack treasure goblins you weren't quite ready for.